# Fitting a Multivariate Normal Model

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, maximum-likelihood, fitting, multivariate-normal-distribution

Is there a standard method for fitting multivariate normal models where $\mu(\theta)$ and $\Sigma(\theta)$ are nonlinear functions of the model parameters?

In my case I have a single vector of observations $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. I can write down the likelihood function for my model but it is too complicated to maximize analytically. Numerical optimizers such as Nelder-Mead are highly dependent on starting parameter values and find only local maxima (of which there are apparently many).

Comment: I use the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to generate initial parameter estimates, if you use Python the scipy library has this built in as the module scipy.optimize.differential_evolution. This scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space and so requires bounds within which to search, however those bounds can be generous.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how the mean and covariance depend on $\theta$?  Because if you can't, you are essentially asking for a general treatise on optimisation theory.

Comment: The natural parameters $\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1} \mu}$ and $-\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}$ are non-convex functions of the parameters in $\theta$ so it looks to be a non-convex optimisation problem.